# Max value of query

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a dataset with:

```
Id.   Code. Update time
222.  A.    1/1/16
222   B.    1/1/17
123   c     1/1/16
123   d.    1/1/17
```

I want the data set to filter to:

```
222   B.    1/1/17
123   d.    1/1/17
```

How do I do the query for this?

Comment: Looks like you want to `SELECT` the second and fourth lines. What is your criteria? My guess: for each `Id`, select the latest `update time`.

Comment: What flavor of SQL?  Sql Server? Oracle? MySQL? (insert other SQL dialects here).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Please do not answer and close as duplicate.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Answer (score 0):

First write a sub-query that finds the latest date for each ID. Then join the sub-query back to the main table to grab the other column(s):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.code, t.updatetime
FROM table t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ID, MAX(updatetime) AS mxtime
 FROM table
 GROUP BY ID) sub
ON t.ID = sub.ID
AND t.updatetime = sub.mxtime
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, this is a simple aggregation query:

```
select id, max(code) as code, max(updatetime) as updatetime
from t
group by id;
```

If this is not what you want, then you need to be clearer about the logic you want to implement.